# Is there a way to plot matrix elements like a heat map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, plot

I'm programming a code where I use a matrix full of 0's and 1's, the idea is to represent a galaxy, so the 0's are like the void and the 1's will be solar systems (for now), later I intend to add more elements. So, I was wondering if there's a way to plot this elements sorta like a heat map (1 = red and 0 = blue). I'd appreciate any ideas or suggestions if you think there's a better way to pose the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `plt.imshow` we can make heat maps you can read more about it here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


matrix = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])


plt.imshow(matrix, cmap='hot', interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My go-to is Plotly for any kind of figure

```
import plotly.express as px

matrix = np.reshape([random.choice([0,1]) for n in range(10000)], (100, 100))

fig = px.imshow(matrix,
                color_continuous_scale=['blue','red'])
fig.show()
```

[image: Figure]